# Update SQL Server trigger to send email

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have this trigger which when the following conditions are met it should send an email:

```
 type = 234
 confirmed_erp = 1
 itemrequestfor = 'P'
```

When I exclude the email section the process works but does not send an email. When I include email section, it does not process any of the lines and does not send email either. Where am I going wrong?

I have left out some columns in the select and the insert for ease of reading, the issue seems to be when I add in the email section after.

```
if @type ='234' AND @CONFIRMED_ERP = 1 AND @itemrequestfor = 'P'
begin
    select @new_id = max(id) 
    from jobr_generic;

    insert into jobr_generic (id, type, jobr_ts, customerno, str_attr1, str_attr3, 
 dec_attr1, str_attr4,str_attr5, str_attr6,str_attr7, str_attr8, str_attr9)
    values (@new_id+1, '235', getdate(), @customerno, @attr1, @attr3, 
            @decattr1, @attr4, @attr5, @attr6, @attr7, @attr8, @attr9,    
            @attr10, @attr11, @attr12, @attr13, @attr14, @attr15, @attr16,   
            @attr17, @attr18, @attr19, @attr20, 1);
end

if @type ='235' AND @CONFIRMED_ERP = 1 AND @itemrequestfor = 'P'
begin
    declare @body2 varchar(1024)
    set @body2 = 'Primal Item: '+@attr16+ ' has been created and is ready 
  for use.'+@NewLineChar+@NewLineChar+'Type: '+@attr4+@NewLineChar+'Desc: 
 '+@attr7+@NewLineChar+'Supplier: '+@attr9+@NewLineChar+'Alias: 
  '+@attr11+@NewLineChar+'Cost centre: '+@attr12+@NewLineChar+'Supplier 
 item number: '+@attr13
  exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
 @profile_name = 'DoNotReplyMailProfile',
 @recipients=@attr6,
 @copy_recipients= 'test@test.com',
 @subject = 'Item',
 @body = @body2,
 @body_format = 'TEXT',
    @exclude_query_output = 1 ;
end
END
```

Comment: Word of advice: a trigger **ought to be** very small, nimble and fast - do **not** do any extensive processing, or long-running operations inside a trigger. I would **strongly recommend** against trying to send out an e-mail from within a trigger.....

Comment: Sure, can you provide any alternative methods that I can achieve the same result? I will then do some research.

Comment: I would **de-couple** the task of registering (inside the trigger) that something needs to be done, and the actual task of doing that step. In the trigger, make an `INSERT` into a "command" (or "tasks-to-do") table and store all the relevent info you need and be done with the trigger right away - and then have a separate e.g. SQL Server Agent Job that checks this "Command" table once every 10, 30, 60 minutes (or whatever frequence you need) and then actually does the job (e.g. sending an e-mail